# Futoshiki C recursive solver

Tags: c, algorithm, backtracking

So i have this program that should solve a futoshiki puzzle in C
wich is loaded from a text file having this formatting :

```
5
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
- - - - v - - - - 
0 > 0 | 0 | 0 | 3
- - - - - - - - - 
0 | 0 < 2 | 0 | 0
- - - - v - - - - 
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4
^ - v - - - - - - 
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

where 5 is the size of the matrix, and the numbers adjcent to the operators `<`, `>`, `^`, `v` must satisfy the condition imposed by them, from the file all the characters on rows are divided by spaces 
eg `0 |`...
So I've managed to load the file, to check if it satisfies the math operators conditions, but I'm stuck on the recursive function

What I'd like to know:

Did i choose the right way to store the matrix or I've should have divided the numbers from the logical operators ?

How could I perform an recursive expansion on the matrix and how could I track the used number in a certain step(in case I would have to backtrack)?

eg. let's say I arrive at `index[j][j]` where `j<n` (size of matrix) , starting from there I would have to decrement `j` ("touching") only numbers and check if the sub-matrix satisfies the conditions

Here's what I've managed to code so far.

where :

`char **readmat(int *n);`     //reads the matrix from the file eliminating the spaces between chars

`void print(char **mat,int n);` //prints the stored matrix

`int check(char **mat,int n);`  //checks if items of a matrix of size n satisfies the math operators

`int expand (char **mat,int n,int i);` //this should be the recursive functions that gets an element at a time and checks if there's any condition to be satisfied, if so, increments it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char **readmat(int *n);
void print(char **mat,int n);
int check(char **mat,int n); 
int expand (char **mat,int n,int i);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  char **mat;
  int n, j;

  mat=readmat(&n);

  if(mat == NULL)
     return 1;

  if(check(mat,n)){
     print(mat,n);
  }
  else if(expand(mat,n,0)==1){
      print(mat,n);
  }
  else {
      printf("Nessuna soluzione trovata.\n");
  }

  for(j=0; j<=n;j++)
       free(mat[j]);
  free(mat);

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}

char **readmat(int *n){
     FILE *fp;
     char *line,nome[100];
     int i,j,k;
     char **mat;

     printf("Inserire il nome del file: ");
     scanf("%s",nome);
     fp=fopen(nome,"r");
     if(fp==NULL){
     printf("Errore apertura file");
     return NULL;
 }

 if(fgets(nome,100,fp)==NULL){
     printf("Formato file non valido\n");
     fclose(fp);
     return NULL;
 }
 if(sscanf(nome,"%d",n)!=1){
     printf("Errore nei parametri del file\n");
     fclose(fp);
     return NULL;    
 }

 (*n)=(((*n)*2)-1);


 mat=(char**)malloc((*n)*sizeof(char*));
 for(i=0;i<=(*n);i++)
    mat[i]=(char*)malloc((*n)*sizeof(char));

 line=(char*)malloc(2*(*n)*sizeof(char));

 i=0;

 while(i<=2*(*n) && fgets(line,2*(*n)+2,fp)!=NULL){
    j=0;
    k=0;
    while(j<=2*(*n)){
        if(line[j]!=' '){
           mat[i][k]=line[j];
           k++;
        }  
        j++;
    }
    i++;
 }   
 return mat;
 //print(mat, (*n));  
}

void print(char **mat,int n){
    int i=0,j=0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
     for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf("%c", mat[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
    }
}

int check(char **mat,int n) {

    int i,j;
    int k=1;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(mat[i][j]=='<'){
                if(mat[i][j-1] >= mat[i][j+1])
                    k=0;                               
            }
            else if(mat[i][j]=='>'){
                if(mat[i][j-1] <= mat[i][j+1])
                    k=0;
            }   
            else if(mat[i][j]=='^'){
                if(mat[i-1][j] >= mat[i+1][j])
                    k=0;    
            }
            else if(mat[i][j]=='v'){
                if(mat[i-1][j] <= mat[i+1][j])
                    k=0;                      
            }                            
        }
    }
    return k;                                
}
int expand (char **mat,int n,int i){

    int j=i/n;
    int k=i%n;
    int p;

    if(i>=n*n){

        return 1;
    }       
    else{
        if((mat[j][k]>47)&&(mat[j][k]<58)){
            if(mat[j][k]=='0'){     
                expand(mat,n,i+2);
            }   
            for (p=(mat[j][k]-48); p<(10-(mat[j][k]-48)); p++) {              
                mat[j][k]=48+p;                        
                if (check(mat,i)) {
              if (expand(mat, n, i+2)) {
                   return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            i-=2;
            mat[j][k]='0';
        }
    }           
    return 0;
}
```

solution of the example : As you can see the logical conditions area clearly satisfied

```
0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
- - - - v - - - - 
1 > 0 | 0 | 0 | 3
- - - - - - - - - 
0 | 0 < 2 | 0 | 0
- - - - v - - - - 
0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4
^ - v - - - - - - 
1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Comment: I'd keep numbers and operators separate. (I'd also keep horizontal and vertical operators separate too.) After all, you only ever want to update the numbers when solving, not the operators.

Comment: Are you sure the example puzzle you posted has a solution? Working it out by hand, I keep getting two 1s in the second row from the bottom.

Comment: @kevin of course it does, you're deffinitely missing something.

Comment: Could you provide the solution, then? Naturally, any good question about an algorithm ought to have a sample input and expected output... :)

Comment: I have edited my post and provided an "hand made" solution

Comment: But a valid futoshiki solution has exactly one instance of the numbers 1 through 5 in each row and column, much like sudoku. Do you need your solution to enforce the "must be a [Latin Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)" constraint? Or are you satisfied with a solution that satisfies the greater-than symbols, even if a number is repeated in a column/row?

Comment: @Kevin well the paper of the exam where I've got the problem from, didn't stated anything about the 1 trough 5 one instance, so I assume that satisfying the math operators is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you store the matrix shouldn't matter too much. You can store it however you like, as long as you can easily get/set the numerical value of each spot, and evaluate whether the operators are satisfied.

Very broadly, you can solve problems of this type by using an algorithm like this:

```
//returns true if this function solved the puzzle, false otherwise.
//gameData will be changed to the solved form of the puzzle if a solution exists, or remain unchanged if no solution exists.
//(so, whatever language you're using, ensure gameData is passed by reference here)
bool solve(gameData){
    if (!isValid(gameData)){return false;}  //oops, puzzle is unsolvable!
    if (isComplete(gameData)){return true;} //puzzle is already solved; no further modification needed.

    //choose a spot on the game board that hasn't been filled in yet.
    int x;
    int y;
    getEmptySpot(gameData, &x, &y);

    //iterate through all the possible values that could go into the empty spot.
    //you don't need anything fancy here to generate legal values for i;
    //if you accidentally supply an invalid value, then isValid()
    //will notice in the next solve() call.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        //try putting i in the empty spot.
        setValue(gameData, x, y, i);
        if (solve(gameData)){ //putting i in the spot led to a solution!
            return true;
        }
    }
    //didn't find a solution :(
    //return gameData to its original state.
    setValue(gameData, x, y, 0);
    return false;
}
```

This algorithm does a brute-force recursive search, trying every possible value for each spot, and backtracking if it enters an illegal state. In the super-worst case, it runs in exponential time, but in practice, the `isValid()` call at the beginning will short-circuit any obviously infeasible branches, so it should finish reasonably quickly for a 5x5 input.

Implementation of isValid, isComplete, getEmptySpot, and setValue will depend on how you defined gameData.

`isValid` should check to see that the game data isn't in an illegal state - in your case, it should check that all the greater-than comparisons are correct, and check that every number appears only once in each row and column. These checks should ignore spots whose value is 0, since they are just a placeholder meaning "not filled in yet".

`isComplete` should check to see that no spots have a "not filled in yet" placeholder. `(isValid(gameData) && isComplete(gameData))` implies that gameData is solved.

`getEmptySpot` should find a spot that hasn't been filled in yet. If you're concerned about speed, it should find a spot with the least number values that can be legally entered. This will reduce the width of the search tree pretty considerably.

Finally, `setValue` should set the given spot to the given value.

Comment: Now I have to go out but I'll look into the code you posted tommorow and tell you if I find it useful,at the first look seems very well commented, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I would

1. remove the matrix size. it is obvious by reading the matrix itself
2. remove pipes and other chars, only leaving the spaces
3. add operators after the matrix, in a special "encoded" format
4. a single function could take the rules and try to solve the matrix

matrix example:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 3
0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 4
0 0 0 0 0 
--
1,3>2,3
2,1>2,2
3,2<3,3
3,3>4,3
4,1<5,1
4,2>5,2
```

After the `--` start the rules, the meaning is clear (to me at least): 
value at row 1, column 3 must be greater than value at row 2, column 3.

etc.

About the solver, I would start as follows:

1. search in the matrix if there's a rule involving a cell with a 2 that must be greater than another cell. If yes, you can immediately insert a 1 in the other cell
2. repeat point 1 for the entire matrix, so that you'll get a new, partially solved matrix as a starting point
3. Same thing as above with 4s with the rule "less than". You can put a 5 in the related cell
4. Now search if there's a row (or column) with 4 numbers filled. If so, the 5th number is obvious.

When you have completed the preceding steps you have a partially (maybe fully if you're lucky) solved matrix, then you have to write a core function that tries every combination but considering the dynamic rules (those in the file) and the static rules (those that make the game).

Comment: well your point is quite valid but keep in mind that this was an exam I had last week and the format of the matrix was the one I posted to make it more difficult (that's why they've also added spaces between chars.